# Replace selector with array item

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach

I would like to archive that I have an Array, with 3-4 Items and then I want to itterate throw all of them and change the selector in the function with the items of the array.

```
let items = ['Name','Person,'New']
```

then my function

```
$('.btn').on("click", function(){do smth});
```

and then the foreach .btn should be like name or person, and I want maybe to add late more Items to the array. How should I do it?

for 3 functions

`$('.name .btn').on("click", function()){do smth.})`

`$('.name .test').on("click", function()){do smth.})`

`$('.name .dosmth').on("click", function()){do smth.})`

Name should be replaced with item of the array

I want unique function for the elements

Comment: So you want to have $('.Name')..., $('.Person')... foreach element in the array?

Comment: yes, that what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
let items = ['name', 'person', 'new']
let elements = [{
    name: 'btn',
    callback: () => {
      // do something
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'test',
    callback: () => {
      // do something
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'dosmth',
    callback: () => {
      // do something
    }
  }
]
items.forEach(item =>
  elements.forEach(element => $(`.${item} .${element.name}`).on("click", element.callback()))
)
```

Comment: But I have multiple Functions, actually 3. How Would I wirte that?

Comment: So you want to call three function on the onclick for each item?

Comment: If the functions all does the same you only need one

Comment: @TryHard11332 Updated answer. Do you want to call the same for all three or different?

Comment: no all three the same

Comment: @LarsFlieger Sorry No I dont want to call the same for all three, how do I do it?

Comment: @TryHard11332 Do you want to call a unique function for each item and element? Or the same for each element? Can you add to your question.

Comment: @LarsFlieger I want unique function for the elements

Comment: @TryHard11332 Does this answer your question?